# Why does OpenShift interfere with my redirects?

Tags: redirect, openshift

I configured both, **europe.example.org** and **example.eu** as domain alias in OpenShift.

When **example.eu** is called (eg via `curl -i http://example.eu`), my OpenShift app's logic sends this HTTP **Location** header in order to perform a redirect:

`Location: http://europe.example.org/?from=example.eu`

However, OpenShift intereferes with what I send, actually submitting the following instead:

`Location: http://example.eu/?from=example.eu`

*This creates an infinite redirect-loop.*

**How can I stop OpenShift from doing that and instead have it pass what my app actually says to?**

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`Location: http://@europe.example.org/?from=example.eu`

Comment: Creative :) Seems to work; Did you mean it as permanent workaround or did you just want to know if it would avoid the actual issue?